# ASUS Nexus 7 2013 USB Driver

Tags: android, eclipse

Good day.
I am using the device mention on my topic on running android application from eclipse.
I can't find my device on run configuration. I am sick of exporting my project and turning it into apk file just to view it on my device.
The errors are:
The drivers for this device is not installed. (Code 28)
There are no compatible drivers for this device.

I tried to update automatically on the internet the driver but couldn't find.
Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should be able to use google's driver for a nexus device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) manual? Especially the part where you [install the Google USB driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)?

Comment: I will check this and will follow. I'll be back after I try to resolve.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
Sorry for being novice.
I have another concern, my tablet is now on developer mode, can I revert it back? :))

Comment: Glad i could help, good luck with your app! Please, accept my answer :)

Comment: Are you in the wrong connection mode on the mobile? It should be connected as a Media Device.

Comment: This link shows you how to remove developer options, however you wont be able to continue debugging your cellphone if you do it. Please read the whole article I'm not sure if other settings is cleared. http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-hide-developer-options-on-android-devices/